# add new relation column in large mysql table from other table in php

Tags: php, mysql, large-data

I have two tables one is master and other is it's items.

Items table have around 12,979,398 data.

I want to add relation column in items table which will Master table id and update all existing records with master id.

I done alter table command but it's not working and it's stuck.

Please let me know easy way to handle and create this successfully.

Thanks in advance
Balraj

Comment: Could you add your source code. That would be helpful for understanding the problem.

Comment: 'Around 12,979,398'? Is that a bit like 13m?

Answer (score 0):

if you already have those data... i will first create an int column 'master_id' with no one kind of key, so the alter table will not have any problem to create it.

Once the column exists, i will update the rows to set the correct master_id. You know... Set items.master_id = master.id where the condition you used to link them

And now, if you wish set any kind of foreign key you will be able to